# How to filter list from data class

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, mvp

I have  JSON response:

```
{
    "response" : [
        {
            "f_name"    : "иВан",
            "l_name"    : "ИваноВ",
            "birthday"  : "1987-03-23",
            "avatr_url" : "https://2.cdn.echo.msk.ru/files/avatar2/2561900.jpg",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {
            "f_name"    : "Петр",
            "l_name"    : "петроВ",
            "birthday"  : null,
            "avatr_url" : "https://2.cdn.echo.msk.ru/files/avatar2/1253126.jpg",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {"f_name"   : "ЕКАТЕРИНА",
        "l_name"    : "пертрова",
        "birthday"  : "1990-01-07",
        "avatr_url" : "",
        "specialty" : [{
            "specialty_id" : 102,
            "name"  : "Разработчик"
            }]

    "specialty" : [{
        "specialty_id" : 102,
        "name"  : "Разработчик"
        }]
```

and data class in Model:

```
 data class Response(
        @SerializedName("avatr_url")
        val avatrUrl: String,
        val birthday: String,
        @SerializedName("f_name")
        val fName: String,
        @SerializedName("l_name")
        val lName: String,
        val specialty: List<Specialty>
    )
    data class Specialty(
        val name: String,
        @SerializedName("specialty_id")
        val specialtyId: Int
    )
```

It is required to filter the list of Response elements to be displayed in the RecyclerView for each profession. I load data for the entire list in Presenter:

```
val data = Employee.repository.getEmployeesInfo() 
                    .response
```

How should I filter the list of items by the specialtyId property to form a list of people of only one profession?

Answer (score 0):

the logic in this method should work:

```
fun filterBySpecialty(employees: List<Response>, specialtyId: Int): List<Response> =
    employees.filter { employee -> 
        employee.specialty.any { specialty -> 
            specialtyId == specialty.specialtyId 
        } 
    }
```